# Can't get custom template tag to work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I just started to work with the custom template tags.

I have the following code in my `forum_tags.py` custom tempates module:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django import template
from django.utils.timesince import timesince

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def time_until(value):
    now = datetime.now()
    try:
        difference = value - now
    except:
        return value

    if difference <= timedelta(minutes=1):
        return 'just now'
    return '%(time)s ago' % {'time': timesince(value).split(', ')[0]}
```

The code must take a string returned by `timesince` template tag and return only the first value from it (splited by ", ").

In my `html` file I use it like so:

```
{% load forum_tags %}
<div class="started">
    <p>{{ obj.pub_date|timesince:forum_time|time_until }}</p>
</div>
```

But I'm still getting the whole string.
What's wrong?

Comment: You know there's a built in `timeuntil` filter, right? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timeuntil Your use case looks a bit odd, so I can't tell if it'll do exactly what you want or not.

Comment: I think timesince gives back a string so you can not substract a datetime object.

Comment: @Jingo yes, I know. I just want to split the string by comma and get only the first value.

Comment: @Oleg9: yet you try to treat the string as a datetime object. That means an exception will be thrown and the original `value` is returned. You need to fix how you handle that.

Comment: The point is that you're calling the built in `timesince` in your template, which returns a string. Then you feed that string into your custom filter, which attempts to subtract a `datetime` from the string. You need to decide what kind of input you want your filter to accept, and write and call it accordingly. Right now it's a muddle of strings and datetimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the updated problem statement:

> All I want is to get the output (string) of the "timesince" function, split the string by the comma and pass only the FIRST value to the template. E.g. timesince returns "1 day, 19 hours", I want to get just "1 day".

I think the best approach would be to expose Python's built in `split` as a filter. A simple implementation would be:

```
@register_filter
def split(value, sep=None):
    return value.split(sep)
```

Expanding to fit the docs recommendations for custom filters:

> Filter functions should always return something. They shouldn’t raise exceptions. They should fail silently. In case of error, they should return either the original input or an empty string – whichever makes more sense.

```
@register_filter
def split(value, sep=None):
    try:
        return value.split(sep)
    except:
        return value
```

I don't like writing a blanket `except` into any code, but you can't control what `value` could be (just what you expect it to be when you call it properly) and that's the only way to be sure it fails silently.

Then use the existing `first` filter in your template.

```
{% load forum_tags %}
<div class="started">
    <p>{{ obj.pub_date|timesince:forum_time|split:","|first }}</p>
</div>
```